# Error when bitbake on meta-browser layer, gn-native package for Yocto zeus

Tags: browser, chromium, yocto

I am trying to generate a Yocto Linux from a Ubuntu 18.04 but run into an error when compiling `gn-native` from Chromium inside `meta-browser` layer. As I just add this layer without modifying it, I am a bit lost and error doesn not talk to me much.

```
>     ERROR: gn-native-80.0.3987.132-r0 do_compile: Execution of '/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/temp/run.do_compile.13120'
> failed with exit code 1:
>     ninja: Entering directory `/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/chromium-80.0.3987.132/out/Release/gn_build'
>     [1/182] CXX base/callback_internal.o
>     FAILED: base/callback_internal.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/callback_internal.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/callback_internal.cc -o base/callback_internal.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/callback_internal.cc:5:
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/callback_internal.h:13:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/memory/ref_counted.h:10:10: fatal error: 'utility' file not found
>     #include <utility>
>              ^~~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [2/182] CXX base/command_line.o
>     FAILED: base/command_line.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/command_line.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/command_line.cc -o base/command_line.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/command_line.cc:5:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/command_line.h:19:10: fatal error: 'map' file not found
>     #include <map>
>              ^~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [3/182] CXX base/environment.o
>     FAILED: base/environment.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/environment.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/environment.cc -o base/environment.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/environment.cc:5:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/environment.h:8:10: fatal error: 'map' file not found
>     #include <map>
>              ^~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [4/182] CXX base/files/file_path_constants.o
>     FAILED: base/files/file_path_constants.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/files/file_path_constants.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path_constants.cc -o
> base/files/file_path_constants.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path_constants.cc:7:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path.h:107:10: fatal error: 'iosfwd' file not found
>     #include <iosfwd>
>              ^~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [5/182] CXX base/files/file.o
>     FAILED: base/files/file.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/files/file.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file.cc -o base/files/file.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file.cc:5:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file.h:10:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
>     #include <string>
>              ^~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [6/182] CXX base/files/file_path.o
>     FAILED: base/files/file_path.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/files/file_path.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path.cc -o base/files/file_path.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path.cc:5:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_path.h:107:10: fatal error: 'iosfwd' file not found
>     #include <iosfwd>
>              ^~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     [7/182] CXX base/files/file_enumerator.o
>     FAILED: base/files/file_enumerator.o 
>     clang++  -MMD -MF base/files/file_enumerator.o.d  -I../../../tools/gn -I. -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -DNDEBUG -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -pthread -pipe -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fdiagnostics-color -isystem/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -std=c++17 -c ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_enumerator.cc -o
> base/files/file_enumerator.o
>     In file included from ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_enumerator.cc:5:
>     ../../../tools/gn/base/files/file_enumerator.h:11:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
>     #include <vector>
>              ^~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/chromium-80.0.3987.132/tools/gn/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 138, in <module>
>         sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
>       File "/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/chromium-80.0.3987.132/tools/gn/bootstrap/bootstrap.py", line 124, in main
>         ['ninja', '-C', gn_build_dir, 'gn', '-w', 'dupbuild=err'])
>       File "/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 190, in check_call
>         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
>     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-C', '/home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/chromium-80.0.3987.132/out/Release/gn_build', 'gn', '-w', 'dupbuild=err']' returned non-zero exit status 1
>     WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
>     ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/tux/yocto-freescale-zeus/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gn-native/80.0.3987.132-r0/temp/log.do_compile.13120
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My fault...
I had to install g++-multilib that was not installed, so basic libraries were not present...

> sudo apt install g++-multilib